# span set and dimension of a code C

Tags: linear-algebra

İf $C$ has the spanning set $S$, where $S = \{V_1, V_2, V_3 \} \subseteq \mathbb{F}_q^n$, then $\dim C = 3$.

Is that statement true?  Why?

Comment: This is difficult to read.  I will attempt to format the LaTeX, but you ought to confirm that I have maintained your original intent.

Answer (score 1):

If $C$ is a linear code, then it constitutes a subspace of the field $\mathbb{F}_q^n$. If your three vectors are linearly independent, then they form a basis for $C$ as a subspace, so by definition $\dim(C)=|S|=3$.

Answer (score 1):

False in general. Leaving the construction of a counterexample to OP as an exercise

Hint: Can you give a set of three linearly dependent vectors in $\mathbb{F}_q^n$?

Answer (score 0):

S is said to be a basis for c if

a)C=

b)S is linearly independent and [S]=dim C

S={V1,V2,V3}

If V1,V2,V3 are linearly independent the dimension of C is 3,the statement is true.

but if V1,V2,V3 are linearly dependent vectors then dim(C)<3,the statement will be false